# How to input a number with a ring?

Tags: input-forms

I want to input a special character just like ①, but I don't find how to. Can Mathematica make it?

Comment: Hi, take a look at `Inset` or `Overlay`.

Comment: The Unicode block Enclosed Alphanumerics `\:2460` - `\:24ff` has a selection of such characters that will display circled numbers up to 20 in _Mathematica_ running on OS X and maybe other operating systems as well.

Comment: Thanks! It works on Windows.., and I found that we can modify the font format, size,color, and so on

Comment: Thanks! but the last one FromCharacterCode[#] & /@ Range[9398, 9449] dosen't seem to work on my Mathematica.

Answer (score 6):

Follow the integer codes (to be used with `FromCharacterCode`) and hexadecimal codes (to be used with `\:`) for enclosed numbers. Although not asked, I added the codes for enclosed letters for completeness.

**Enclosed numbers**

```
FromCharacterCode[9450] (* \:24ea *)
FromCharacterCode /@ Range[9312, 9331] (* from \:2460 to \:2473 *)
FromCharacterCode /@ Range[12881, 12895] (* from \:3251 to \:325f *)
FromCharacterCode /@ Range[12977, 12991] (* from \:32b1 to \:32bf *)
```

[image]

```
FromCharacterCode /@ Range[9451, 9470] (* from \:24eb to \:24ff *)
FromCharacterCode /@ Range[10102, 10131] (* from \:2776 to \:2793 *)
```

[image]

**Enclosed letters**

```
FromCharacterCode /@ Range[9398, 9449] (* from to \:24b6 to \:24e9 *)
```

[image]

**Remarks**

As mentioned by @m_goldberg in his [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101390/how-to-input-a-number-with-a-ring#comment275071_101390), characters may not displayed on some operating systems, and as mentioned by @WangFeiBoy in his [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101390/how-to-input-a-number-with-a-ring#comment275256_101390), the `Style` of the characters can be modified to some extent.

Answer (score 1):

**Generic code:**

```
Graphics[{Circle[], Text[x^2 + y^2 < 1, {0, 0}]}]
```

**Output:**

[image: generic example]

**Specific code:**

```
Graphics[{Circle[], Text[1]}, ImageSize -> 24]
```

**Output:**

[image: specific example]

**Reference:**
[Graphics](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html)
[Circle](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Circle.html)
[Text](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text.html)

Comment: Thanks for your meaningful answer! but what I want to get is an "Enclosed Alphanumerics", just like what @m_goldberg said

Comment: @WangFeiBoy, I do apologise for not providing the ideal solution. Could you please edit your question to include this requirement? What is the ideal output you are looking for?

Comment: Sorry I didn't express that clealy, but I think @Xavier have answered  my doubts well. In fact your answer can solve my problem as well, in spite of some inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

user31159's solution seems not always working at least on my system,

```
FromCharacterCode /@ Range[12881, 12895]
```

shows

[image]

I found this solution for numbers below 100

```
Table[Framed[i, ImageSize -> {25, 25}, Alignment -> Center, 
  RoundingRadius -> 100], {i, 1, 99}]
```

which gives

[image]

Also no problem for bigger number, but you need a sightly bigger circle!

```
Table[Framed[i, ImageSize -> {32, 32}, Alignment -> Center, 
  RoundingRadius -> 100], {i, 100, 110}]
```

gives

[image]

Even better, I made a function `circledNumber` that can control the size of circle and automatically adjust size of number to fit the circle. It only works for integer number smaller than 1000.

```
circledNumber[int_, size_] := Module[{scale},
   If[int < 100, scale = 0.7, scale = 0.5];
   Framed[Style[int, size*scale], ImageSize -> {size, size}, 
    Alignment -> Center, RoundingRadius -> 100, 
    ContentPadding -> False, FrameMargins -> 0]]
```

below is an example

```
Table[circledNumber[i, 
  size], {i, {9, 99, 999}}, {size, {10, 50, 100}}]
```

[image]