# Labeling backplanes in a 3D plot using "enclosed numbers" (i.e. ①, ② ...)

Tags: plotting, graphics

When we use `ListPlot3D` or `Plot3D` in *Mathematica*, a box is generated to contain the plot, as shown below. In the drawings below, I intentionally did not draw any plot in the box for the sake of clarity and generality; however in my problem I am using `ListPlot3D`.

[image: Empty box]

I show three axes as they would be generated by e.g. `Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 3}]]`.

I would like to draw [enclosed numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enclosed_Alphanumerics) on the faces of this box at the following coordinates:

```
① -> {1.5,   0,  0}
② -> {2.0, 1.5,  0}
③ -> {1.0, 3.0,  0}
④ -> {  0, 1.5,  0}
⑤ -> {1.0, 1.5, -1}
```

Here is a rough approximation of what I would like the end result to look like:

[image: box with axes and numbers]

Comment: Have you tried using [`Inset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html)? If your problem is how to get the circle-enclosed numbers, see [How to input a number with a ring](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/101390/27951).

Comment: We have to play with theta in Rotate[Style["enclosed(number)"], theta] to lie on exact on a surface. but without that desired case is automatically lies on a surface.

Comment: Take a look at `Framed` with the `RoundingRadius` option. A suitably large `RoundingRadius` will result in a circled expression. See e.g. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18823/131

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear[circle]
circle[n_Integer /; 1 <= n <= 10] :=
 Style[FromCharacterCode[9311 + n], FontFamily -> "Arial Unicode MS"]
circle[n_Integer /; 1 <= n <= 10, size_Integer?(# > 0 &)] :=
 Style[FromCharacterCode[9311 + n], size, FontFamily -> "Arial Unicode MS"]

Show[
 Plot3D[f[x, y],
   {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 3},
   ViewAngle -> 0.50, ViewPoint -> {2, -2.5, 0.7}
 ],
 Graphics3D[{
    Black,
    Text[circle[1, 24], {1.5, 0, 0}],
    Text[circle[2, 24], {2, 1.5, 0}],
    Lighter@Gray,
    Text[circle[3, 24], {1, 3, 0}],
    Gray,
    Text[circle[4, 24], {0, 1.5, 0}],
    Style[Text[circle[5, 24], {1, 1.5, -1}], FontSlant -> Italic]
  }]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

A generic solution is to combine the plot and text with `Show`.

```
img = Plot3D[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}];
Show[img,
 Graphics3D[{Text[Style["Top", Red, 25], {0, 0, 1}], 
   Text[Style["Left", Red, 25], {-1, 0, 0.5}],
   Text[Style["Front", Red, 25], {0, -1,0.5}]}]]
```

[image]

You can always add additional feature to your text.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not put them in circles! although MarcoB commented.

Comment: @Ackaran, have a look at `CharacterRange["\:2460", "\:2468"]`.